# Two different chrome browsers at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code that I run from two different files in two different consoles in Spyder. I need to do different tasks with each browser but it does create a second driver, the second instance of the script just use the first browser... How to separate the tasks and have two browser please ? I thought two different consoles was multithreading, this is not the case ?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
except SessionNotCreatedException:
    os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome
browser.get('http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you wanted but you can have 2 different browsers with that code for example :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()

driver1.get('https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl')
driver2.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thanks but I do not run the two browser in the same script, I have two separate main.py There are two consoles...

Comment: You ve got two different files and you wrote you want them to run in two different browsers? I think I didn't understand your problem...

Comment: yes I'm using two scripts (two different programs) so I need each program opens its own browser

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solve your problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver

amount = int(input('[?] amount browsers '))

driver = []

while amount != len(driver):
    driver.append(webdriver.Chrome())

# if u want the to make a ctrl+c ctrl+v browser use this down here
for i in range(len(driver)):
    driver[i].get('https://www.google.com/')

#else use this
driver[0].get('https://www.google.com/')
driver[1].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not run the two browser in the same script, I have two separate main.py There are two consoles...